# Framing Advice: Building a free standing stud wall for a shower backing

Tags: framing, carpentry, timber-framing

I am trying to determine if my stud wall would be strong enough if it was only attached to the existing wall frame and floor joists. It would also have the track attached for the shower door which will be attached to another wall. The wall dimensions would be 2000mm x 760mm not connected to the ceiling. The same width as my shower tray and height as the doors. Is it a bad idea not connecting it to the ceiling?

On the back of the wall I plan to have some small floating shelves for light weight items.

Appreciate any advice thanks!

Comment: Diagram, please. Your description is not detailed enough. Please take the [tour].

Comment: It probably will stay up as long as no one slips.  Would it be hard to attach to ceiling?  Even a stud or two going all the way up will help stabilize it.

Comment: Your dimensions are metric, indicating that you're not building with 2x4s, but are you building with something similar? That's roughly 50x100mm. Going up to 50x150mm would add some strength & stability.

Comment: @FreeMan, 18mm of sheathing on both sides is probably a better use of that extra 50mm than wider framing.

Comment: @FreeMan   If OP is Canadian, measurements can be mixed.  We are weird.

Comment: y'all do take after the British that way, @crip659. :)

Answer (score 2):

A knee wall or pony wall can support a shower door and shelving.

Typically a question like this is focused on whether a *hinged* shower door at the outer edge of such wall will be adequately supported. And then the answer is yes, with various tricks to ensure the wall is stiff enough.  In your case however, a sliding shower door with a top rail can be built so the top rail provides a lot of rigidity to the wall.  The rail, or some subtle structure above it, can provide strength that a ceiling normally would.

So some of the tricks normally used in this situation may not be necessary.

There are lots of questions on this site about how to stiffen a wall like this so the outer top corner won't wobble, and also lots of videos on youtube etc.  It's a common problem, that you don't even particularly have given your shower rail!